# PHP PDO queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a dbfunctions class that has the functions to retrieve and write data to database. However, the retrieval doesn't work and I can't understand why it doesn't work.

The read functions looks like this:

```
public function haeParametreittaTietokannasta($f_sql) {
    try {
        $this->sql_lause = $this->db->prepare($f_sql);
        $this->haku = $this->sql_lause->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        die("Tapahtui virhe tietoja noudettaessa : " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    if(!$this->haku) {
        $this->tulos = $this->haku->fetchAll();
        return $this->tulos;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} // END FUNCTION
```

And this is how I call the function:

```
$countries = $dabase->haeParametreittaTietokannasta("SELECT * FROM countries");
```

The query always returns false, and I've tried showing error info and it says: **array ( 0 => '00000', 1 => NULL, 2 => NULL, )** (And yes, I have created a new object in the main code.)

I've just started to learn PHP and there might be a simple error I just can't see...

Comment: What's the $this->sql_lause->execute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong if condition:

```
if(!$this->haku) {
```

should be

```
if($this->haku) {
    $this->tulos = $this->sql_lause->fetchAll();
```

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns a boolean value. You can't use it for `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Didn't help. Now the query throws a fatal error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object" when trying to fetch results.

Comment: @Avaronald Do a `var_dump($this->haku);`